# Add blog to Rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs, jekyll

I have a Rails app on Heroku with a Jekyll blog located at blog.myapp.com. I want to move the blog to www.myapp.com/blog/. What's the best way to do this? I'm happy to ditch Jekyll if there is an easier option. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Bloggy](https://github.com/zbruhnke/bloggy) seems to be what you're looking for.

"Bloggy is a simple gem that helps you generate a jekyll blog within your rails application by using generator commands similar to the ones you are used to already."

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the `base-url` configuration to `/blog` for this to work.

https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Configuration